# Gulp, Browserify, Webpack, Ansible, Docker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, workflow

I am beginning to learn about workflow + deployment tools. So far...

I understand that Browserify allows you to easily bundle code and reference it in the browser, similar to how npm modules are referenced in node. However, the idea of using npm modules in the browser seems wrong. Why would we want to regularly use modules originally developed for the server, to be used on the client side?

I understand gulp to be an automation tool that allows you to easily automate the compilation of files (i.e. sass), uglify and then compress javascript files. But I can't seem to understand what 'Ansible' is used for? Is it just an alternative to gulp?

Docker to me is container technology, basically an alternative to VirtualBox/Vagrant. Is that correct?

I am interested in learning the best tools for node.js development. Please let me know if I am missing any other important pieces of technology. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my (admittedly limited) experience with Ansible, I would say that your assessment is only partially correct.

Gulp is used to take your source code and put it through a series of automated build steps for you.

Ansible is also used for automation, but on a different domain. Where I have seen it used, Ansible is generally used for things like system provisioning, automated software installation, and things of that nature when setting up environments.

So, they accomplish similar things, but in separate domains. Gulp takes your code through a series of automated build steps to get it ready to be processed by the browser, and Ansible is generally used to set a machine up with the proper environments and tools to properly run the software that needs to be run on it.